# where to place tags within php pages

Tags: html

I am building up a website with the structure below. But is the `<html>` and `<head>` tag going in my index page, or should that go in my header.php, and then `</body>` and `</html>` in the footer?

```
header.php
// In here I have my navbar, topbar etc there is on all pages.

index.php

include ('header.php')

<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
     Content
  </body>
</html>

include ('footer.php');
footer.php
// Footer is the same on all pages
```

or is this more correct?

```
header.php
<html>
  <head>
  </head>

index.php
  <body>
     Content
  </body>

footer.php
</html>
```

Comment: Didn't get you. Use those tags wherever required. It's not like - `one tag for all the webpages`

Comment: Don't get disappointed. Downvotes aren't important. Please try to express yourself in a better manner.

Comment: Ok I am sorry. I just try my best all the time, and I always get downvoted, and stackoverflow is gonna close my profile. I will just edit my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would structure it so the html / head / body tags are only inside index.php.

index.php:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        include 'navigation.php';

        // default displays page welcome.php
        // otherwise get page name from query string
        $page = 'welcome.php';

        if (!empty($_GET['page'])) {
            $page = $_GET['page'].'.php';
        }

        include $page;

        include 'footer.php';
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

navigation.php:

```
<div class="nav">...</div>
```

welcome.php:

```
<div class="container">
    Welcome page content...
</div>
```

footer.php:

```
<div class="footer">...</div>
```

Now you could have another page  file like

about.php:

```
<div class="container">
    About page content...
</div>
```

and view it by going to `index.php?page=about`.